# find the pdf of $Y$, given that $Y=1-X^{2}$, $f_{X}(x)=\frac{3}{8}(x+1)^{2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with density function

$f_{X}(x)=\frac{3}{8}(x+1)^{2}, \; -1 < x < 1$.

Find the density function of $Y=1-X^{2}$. The answer given is

$f_{X}(x)=\frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{-1/2} + \frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{1/2}, \; 0 < y < 1$.

can someone help me

until now i thought it was something like that

$f_{Y}(y)=\frac{3}{16}(1-\sqrt{1-y})^{2}(1-y)^{-1/2} + \frac{3}{16}(1+\sqrt{1-y})^{2}(1-y)^{-1/2}, \; 0 < y < 1$.

Comment: Hint: Separate $Y= 1-X^2$ to two monotone functions. Then apply transformations of random variables formula.

Comment: yes, i did, which should be: $x=-\sqrt{1-y}$ and $x=\sqrt{1-y}$, but i found the equations that i added in the post @Kyle

Comment: First of all, it should be $f_Y(y)$ on the lhs.  Second I have no idea what formula you were using. Try this: $$F_Y(y)=P(1-X^2\leq y)= P(X\geq \sqrt{1-y})+P(X\leq -\sqrt{1-y})=1-F_X(\sqrt{1-y})+F_X(-\sqrt{1-y}).$$ 
Now take derivative on both sides.

Comment: @Kyle i was using the theorem for transformation $f_{Y}(y) = f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|$, and of course is $f_{Y}(y)$ lol

Comment: and if i take derivatives, i will obtain the equation in the initial post $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{3}{16}(1-\sqrt{1-y})^{2}(1-y)^{-1/2} + \frac{3}{16}(1+\sqrt{1-y})^{2}(1-y)^{-1/2}, \; 0 < y < 1$

Comment: Sigh...Take derivative:
$$f_Y(y)=f_X(\sqrt{1-y})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}}+f_X(-\sqrt{1-y})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-y}} =\text{ the answer you have}=\frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{-1/2}+\frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{1/2}$$

Comment: And yes all you need was to expand it...

Comment: omg, now i got it, in the end i will have $\frac{3}{8}(2-y)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}}$ which is the same as $\frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{-1/2}+\frac{3}{8}(1-y)^{1/2}$, this is trick @Kyle